# Easily pass values in a list as parameters to a method

Tags: java

Is there any easy way to pass all the values in a arbitrary length List as parameters to a method. In the following code, for example, I would want the params in method2 to be a sequence of the values residing in the params List (but without the List structure). Because the list is of arbitrary length, I can't just run through a loop and assign each value in the list to a variable, and then pass those variables to method2.

```
void method1( List<Double> params ){
    void method2(params...)
}
```

Thanks! ~ryan

Comment: What is the problem with passing the parameters as a list?

Answer (score 3):

You can declare

```
public void method2(Double... doubles) {
}
```

See the [Java varargs documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

For method2 to be able to receive a variable number of arguments you need to declare it this way:

```
void method2(Double ... args)
```

In this case, args will be a Double[].

What you need to do in method1 is to convert your List to a Double[].

Here's a sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

    list.add(1.0);
    list.add(2.0);
    list.add(3.0);

    method1(list);
}

public static void method1(List<Double> list) {
    method2(list.toArray(new Double[] {}));
}

public static void method2(Double... args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(args[i]);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

How about this way?

```
void method1(Double... params ){
    method2(Arrays.asList(params));
}
```

This would allow you to do things like

```
method1(1.0);
method1(1.0, 2.0);
method1(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
method1(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
```